# jquery onclick event to mouse scroll

Tags: jquery, css

```
        $header.each( function() {

            var t       = jQuery(this),
                button  = t.find('.button');

            button.click(function(e) {

                t.toggleClass('hide');

                if ( t.hasClass('preview') ) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }

            });

        });
```

In above Code i want to change 
    button.click event 
to 
    mouse scroll.

i.e i want to remove button and want css effect direct on mouse scroll.

Comment: change `button.click(` to `button.scroll(` see [here](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/), is that what you're looking for?

Comment: i tried but no luck. .

Comment: oh sorry, the scroll listener should be attached to the body not to the button. so like `$("body").scroll(handler)`

Comment: Yup  it works but behaving strangely. i think its counting every scroll how to limit the scroll.

Comment: how exactly do you want to limit it? every mouse scroll or every distance or...? it depends on your need

Comment: on first scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's the complete answer. To listen to the first scroll, you could do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var firstScroll = false;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if(!firstScroll) {
            firstScroll = false;
            // Put your code here..
        }
    });
});
```

This will always listen to scrolling event, but only run your code on the first scroll. The more efficient an elegant way is to detach the listener after running your code, which will result in running it only once then stops listening.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        // Put your code here..
        $(window).off("scroll");
    });
});
```

I hope that helps.